# Setting up Auth0 in React Native/Expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, auth0

I set up Auth0 in React Native (using Expo iOS app Xcode simulator). When "login" is invoked, it doesn't run "authorize()". It's not taking me to the Auth0 login page. For my callback URL in Auth0, I set it to localhost:19000 (which is the same as my expo-client).

```
import React from 'react';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Button, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import {useAuth0, Auth0Provider} from 'react-native-auth0';

const Home = () => {
  const {authorize, clearSession, user} = useAuth0();

  const login = async () => {
    try {
      await authorize();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }

  const onLogout = async () => {
    try {
      await clearSession();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('log out canceled');
    }
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {!user && <Button onPress={login} title="Log in" />}
      {user && <Text>Logged in as {user.name}</Text>}
    </View>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Auth0Provider domain={"ihavemydomainhere} clientId={"ihavemyclientidhere"}>
      <Home />
    </Auth0Provider>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

export default App;
```

Comment: It seems impossible for `login()` to not run `authorize()`. What makes you think that is what's happening?

Comment: When I open my Expo Go App and press on “login”, it doesn’t do anything.

Comment: Does it log anything at all? Perhaps you could add some debugging logs, eg `console.log("Starting login")`

Comment: Did you manage to fix it? I think running eas build and running the development build should work. I'm asking because when it works, even after authorize(), it redirects but { user } always just remains null

Answer (score 3):

`react-native-auth0` use native code which is not compatible with Expo Go. That’s why is not doing anything. Try building a dev build, that should work.

Source: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/react-native-expo/interactive (the WARN message states “ This SDK is not compatible with "Expo Go" app. It is compatible only with Custom Dev Client and EAS builds.”)

Hope that helps